# Another incorrect declined flags warning

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags

I just went to flag a question as spam. It was definitely spam and has subsequently been deleted by Community. I got a warning

> Some of your flags have been declined recently. Please review them...

(Apologies if the wording is not quite right.)

My last declined flag was 28th December, and before that one was on 10th December, against a background of approximately 50 flags raised in the same period, with all (I think) marked helpful. Previous declined flag was early November.

This doesn't appear to be a 10% failure rate. Overall I have around 35 declined flags against over 2500 helpful ones in two years - about 1.5%

Something's up, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 3):

If I had to guess, it was probably due to some old close vote flags finally being declined in the review queue. Since the time period for this is based on when flags are cleared, not when they was cast, it might not be all that easy to find the declined flags in your history.

In any case, it looks like the warning got lifted about when you posted this, so this has passed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I usually keep an eye on the flags so I know not much has changed. The warning only appeared for a couple of hours so I suspect the developers were Doing Something...