# Flag decline warning appearing seemingly outside the stated conditions

Tags: support

When doing some reviewing, I saw this message for the first time today.

> Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!

Curious, I did some research and found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268568/incorrect-declined-flags-warning) and [this (very informative) answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/261369) that states the message should be shown when you've raised >= 10 flags in the last 7 days and >= 10% were declined.  I've raised 12 flags in the last 7 days, of which only 1 has been declined, so I'm confused why I see this.

Obviously, I could ignore it (I do disagree with the decline, but life's too short, and I've read all the stuff on here about it being an automated process).  However, I'm wondering if it's a bug (although I find it extremely unlikely) or whether something else is happening that I should be aware of and may help me improve what I'm doing.

Two final bits of potentially relevant information:

- 4 of the 12 flags I raised in the last 7 days are still active - could it be that that means the % is calculated as 1/8?
- I considered [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283568/838992), but I'm pretty sure that "an old flag recently declined" is not responsible, because other than my very first flag, which has been declined for ages, this is the first and only so far that has been declined.

Anyway - I'd be grateful for any suggestions as to why I might be seeing the warning in my situation, in the hope of improving how I operate on the site if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I believe it only counts if the flags _were handled_ in the last 7 days. I had this issue last week, and it required me to jump back a page or two to see the declined (_yet still deleted_) ones.

Comment: Unless there's a more recent reverting of this, [in November the limit was changed from >10 to >6 and 10%](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243601/266735) which would indeed, according to your 4 flags still active statement, cause you to have hit 10% declined.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably what happened, it makes sense of all the circumstances. Nice spot in the answer you linked.